# Is a new pointer created in stack every time we create a new node in a linked list?

Tags: c++, linked-list

I just started learning linked list today and I am not able to understand the following concept:

```
class Node {
public:
    int data;
    node* next;
    Node(int d){
    data = d;
    next = NULL;
    }
};
void insertAfter(Node* prev_node, int new_data)  
{  
    if (prev_node == NULL)  
    {  
        cout << "the given previous node cannot be NULL";  
        return;  
    } 
    Node* new_node = new Node(new_data);   
    new_node->next = prev_node->next;  
    prev_node->next = new_node;  
}
```

This is normally the code we would write to insert element in a linked list

So from what i understand from `Node* new_node = new Node(new_data);` we a create a pointer n which is capable of storing the address of node type. The new keyword initializes/makes memory for the object in the free store and then returns its address and thus every time we keep inserting a node, a pointer that points to that particular node is created in the stack.

So if this is the case and we have a large set of nodes, wouldn't the pointers that point to the new nodes we create consume a lot of space in the stack, which ultimately proves it to have a high memory usage? I just want to understand if there is any flaw in my understanding. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Depends on the implementation.  For example, `std::list` is a mystery as for it's implementation.  You can have a linked list system that uses registers as pointers and registers do not live on the stack.

Comment: The pointer itself is gone by the time the program reaches `}` that ends the scope in which it was declared (just like any other automatic storage variable). The `Node` to which it points to will stay until you call `delete`.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot, you can implement a linked list data structure using an array.  There are no pointers.  There are integral indices, but no pointers.

Comment: Let's have some fun.  Change your `new_node` pointer to `static Node * new_node;`  This will place the pointer in the "global" memory area, and not the stack.  In other words, there are issues with your understanding.

Comment: Expanding on Yksisarvinen's comment, `new_node` only exists until the end of `insertAfter`, so there is never more than one `new_node` at a time. What it pointed at, the object from `new Node(new_data);`, lives on and is accessible through the `next` pointer it was assigned to in the preceding node. Do not conflate the pointer and the pointed-at object. The former is merely a way to find the latter.

Comment: One of the best ways to understand linked lists is through visualizing them by drawing a lot of pictures.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews i think you may not have understand my question correctly. Even if we use static node it will place the pointer in the global space right? while in the piece of code in the question it occupies space in the stack. But it still occupies space in the memory right? So if we have a large data set, wouldnt it be occupying a large amount of pointers, may it be in the global memory or in the stack?

Comment: @NayanShenoy No, because there is only 1 pointer present, the `new_node` variable.  Variables do not just hang around forever, like you are claiming. They disappear when they are no longer needed. When `insertAfter()` is called, it creates a new variable, and when it exits then that variable goes away (unless it is `static`, in which case it just gets reused the next time `insertAfter()` is called).

Comment: @NayanShenoy:  I'm demonstrating that pointers are not always placed on the stack.  Pointers can be placed in other places.  Pointers can even be allocated from dynamic memory.

Comment: *"wouldn't the pointers that point to the new nodes we create consume a lot of space in the stack"* -- Do you expect them to consume more space than other types? For example, if you added the line `long long number = new_data * 2;` to your function, would you expect this to consume a similar amount of space compared to `new_node`?

Comment: *"This is normally the code we would write"* -- I'm going to nitpick a bit here. While I'll assume it was not your intent, I find this phrasing presumptuous and wrong. This is not the code that **I** would normally write. The code I would write likely would allow `Node::next` to be set in the constructor, which could lead to code that side-steps your question. So I think it would be better to replace "normally" with "commonly" and "the" with "a", then rearrange the words to flow better. One possible replacement: *"This is code commonly written"*

Answer (score 1):

`new_node` is a local variable of `insertAfter()`.

Like any variable, `new_node` has [scope](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope) associated with it, and it is no longer valid for use once it goes out of scope.  In this case, its scope is the `insertAfter()` function, and it goes out of scope when `insertAfter()` exits.

Whether or not `new_node` is stored on the stack is an *implementation detail* of the compiler and platform which your code is running on.  It might be stored in a CPU register instead, for instance.  That is for the compiler to decide.  But what is important is that in this example, it simply has [automatic storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration):

> **automatic** storage duration. The storage for the object is allocated at the beginning of the enclosing code block and deallocated at the end. All local objects have this storage duration, except those declared `static`, `extern` or `thread_local`.

So, every time `insertAfter()` is called, there is only 1 `new_node` variable in scope, and it goes away when `insertAfter()` exits.  So, you will NOT "*consume a lot of space in the stack, which ultimately proves it to have a high memory usage*", because the memory for the variable is deallocated when it goes out of scope.

Answer (score -3):

Not necessarily. You can allocate a new node without storing the pointer anywhere.

In your case, you are storing it in `new_node`.

```
Node* new_node = new Node(new_data);
```

We don't know for certain if `new_node` is on the stack though. It could be somewhere else, including simply stored in a register.

Normally, if you allocate many node, you'll only store the node pointer in the linked nodes. And if you store it, as your code does above, the same variable will be used to store the node pointer of the next node.

So you are not allocating a bunch of memory on the stack.